# how to read data from text file in struct with different number of words in lines in c programming?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to read data in struct from text file which I want to print same as original file.

Here is my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Member{
    char *name;
    int age;
    int id;
    char *town;
}Member;

int main() {

    FILE *file = fopen("member.txt", "r");
    FILE *newFile = fopen("new_member.txt", "w");

    int counter=0, line = 10;

    Member *member = malloc(sizeof(Member)*line);

    for(int i =0; i<line; i++){
        int len = 12;
        char *name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        name [len] = '\0';
        int age;
        int id;
        char *town = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        town [len] = '\0';

        fscanf(file, "%s %i %i %s\n", name, &age, &id, town);

        member[counter].name = name;
        member[counter].age =age;
        member[counter].id = id;
        member[counter].town = town;

        counter++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < counter-1; i++){

        fprintf(newFile, "%s %d %d %s\n", member[i].name, member[i].age, member[i].id, member[i].town);
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(newFile);

    printf("Successful\n");

    return 0;
}
```

member.txt

```
John 23 3456 Edinburgh
Robert 33 4567 London
Peter 45 4345 
Cary 56 12345 
Dian 45 4587 Norfolk
Will 32 3453 Essex
Paul 56 7896 York
Alisha 78 1234 Peterbourgh
Brandon 45 3214 Brighton
Eli 39 5234 Oxford
```

I am getting the result.
new_member.txt

```
John 23 3456 Edinburgh
Robert 33 4567 London
Peter 45 4345 Cary
56 12345 4345 
Dian 45 4587 Norfolk
Will 32 3453 Essex
Paul 56 7896 York
Alisha 78 1234 Peterbourgh
Brandon 45 3214 Brighton
```

how can I print same as orginal file? Please note; I am trying to read data in STRUCT. My struct is reading third line and taking name from fourth line as town. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the town name for few of the cases such as

```
Peter 45 4345 
Cary 56 12345
```

But when you try to read it thru `fscanf`, compiler is expecting town name to be present;

```
fscanf(file, "%s %i %i %s\n", name, &age, &id, town);
```

This data will be taken from the next line and so on.

If this is situation, then you can use `fgets`, `sscanf` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sudipta Kumar Sahoo. I tried as you suggested. But, fgets, sscanf doesn't read file in struct.

Answer (score 0):

This works but only if the word of the town is not included in a line in the text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Member{
    char *name;
    int age;
    int id;
    char *town;
}Member;

int main() {

FILE *file = fopen("member.txt", "r");
FILE *newFile = fopen("new_member.txt", "w");
char* lines;
lines = (char *)malloc(40*sizeof(char));
int counter=0, line = 10;
int i;
Member *member = malloc(sizeof(Member)*line);

for(i=0; i<line; i++){
    int age;
    int id;
    while(fgets(lines, 40, file)!=NULL){

        char *name = (char *)malloc(13*sizeof(char));
        char *town = (char *)malloc(13*sizeof(char));
        if(sscanf(lines, "%s %i %i %s", name, &age, &id, town)==4){
            member[counter].name = name;
            member[counter].age =age;
            member[counter].id = id;
            member[counter].town = town;
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            member[counter].name = name;
            member[counter].age =age;
            member[counter].id = id;
            member[counter].town = "\0";
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

for(i= 0; i < counter; i++){

    fprintf(newFile, "%s %d %d %s\n", member[i].name, member[i].age, member[i].id, member[i].town);
}

fclose(file);
fclose(newFile);

printf("Successful\n");

return 0;
```

}

If you want you can change this:

```
            else{
            member[counter].name = name;
            member[counter].age =age;
            member[counter].id = id;
            member[counter].town = "\0";
            counter++;
            }
```

to this:

```
            else{
            printf("The line of %s is not valid", name);
            }
```

and so your new text will only include valid lines.

Comment: The problem with your code was that you read the file word by word and when there was no town for your program to read, it read the next word which was the next name. You should first split the file to lines and then manipulate each line separately.

Comment: @MHR Would you care to respond to any of our answers?

Comment: Thanks @George Bou. I am trying to read the member.txt file in struct as it is so that I can rearrange the file. My codes work if there is town name in third and fourth lines or all lines have same number of words. thanks for your afford. I don't know how to do it or if it possible at all in my way. :(

Comment: by the way, I care and I appreciate everybody's answer. thanks (y) @George Bou

Answer (score -1):

Try use getline(), strtok(), atoi() to get your data.